# iOS6 contentInset in UIWebview behaves differently from iOS7

Tags: ios7, ios6, uiwebview, uiscrollview, contentsize

I attempt to add spaces in Webview so the content fits the webview nicely like implementing UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. The webview's superview is fixed with 320 * 200, and the webview's content size varies but are small enough to fit in the size. Everything works fine except when using iOS 6.

```
float verticalInset = (self.frame.size.height - fitSize.height) / 2;
float horizontalInset = (self.frame.size.width - fitSize.width) / 2;
wv.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(verticalInset, horizontalInset, verticalInset, horizontalInset);
wv.center = self.center;
```

fitSize is correctly calculated, because if i just set webview's frame to the size, the content fits perfectly. However, that won't fill up its superview when zoomed in.

It seems like when I change the contentInset in iOS 6 it doesn't resize its content to fit the result frame (frame - inset); but iOS 7 does resize it. Is there any solution to fix this difference?